# Convert method syntax to query syntax

Tags: c#, linq, linq-query-syntax, linq-method-syntax

Is there any way to automatically convert from linq method syntax to query syntax?

E.G.:
I want to automatically convert it:

```
var aux = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"c:\")
                .Where(directory => directory.Contains("xxx"))
                .ToList();
```

to it:

```
var aux = (from directory in Directory.EnumerateDirectories(@"c:\")
                  where directory.Contains("xxx")
                  select directory).ToList();
```

Comment: There are some tools out there such as resharper and maybe linqpad (though i think it needs a db). This is a question asking for tools and SO is not the place for such questions.

Comment: Method syntax has more features than query syntax, so: unlikely.

Comment: Short answer: no, unless you use 3rd party tools

Comment: All these tools only do the reverse.